# Converting Ehcache CacheManager (v 3.x) to Spring CacheManager without XML configuration

Tags: java, spring, ehcache, spring-cache, ehcache-3

I'm trying to use Ehcache manager in my application. I would like to setup it without xml configuration.
I have next dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
    <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I have such CacheManager bean:

```
@Bean
public org.springframework.cache.CacheManager cacheManager() {
    org.ehcache.CacheManager mainPageCache = CacheManagerBuilder
            .newCacheManagerBuilder()
            .withCache("mainPageCache", CacheConfigurationBuilder
                    .newCacheConfigurationBuilder(
                            Pageable.class,
                            Collection.class,
                            ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(10))
                    .withExpiry(ExpiryPolicyBuilder
                            .timeToLiveExpiration(Duration
                                    .of(10, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))))
            .build(true);
    // ...
}
```

Is it possible to convert Ehcache CacheManager to Spring CacheManager?
I think there should be something like: `return new JCacheCacheManager(/*some code*/);`

Comment: That cache manager that you have built is not using JCache at all so you need to do that first, see http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.0/107.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't simply convert an ehcache CacheManager to a spring CacheManager.

You can use `org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider` to get a `javax.cache.CacheManager` and give that to `org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheCacheManager` which is an implementation of `org.springframework.cache.CacheManager` for jcache (aka jsr107).

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.cache.CacheManager;
import javax.cache.Caching;

import org.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration;
import org.ehcache.config.ResourcePools;
import org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheConfigurationBuilder;
import org.ehcache.config.builders.ResourcePoolsBuilder;
import org.ehcache.config.units.EntryUnit;
import org.ehcache.config.units.MemoryUnit;
import org.ehcache.core.config.DefaultConfiguration;
import org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheCacheManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {


    @Bean
    public JCacheCacheManager jCacheCacheManager() {
        JCacheCacheManager jCacheManager = new JCacheCacheManager(cacheManager());
        return jCacheManager;
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {

        ResourcePools resourcePools = ResourcePoolsBuilder.newResourcePoolsBuilder()
                .heap(2000, EntryUnit.ENTRIES)
                .offheap(100, MemoryUnit.MB)
                .build();


        CacheConfiguration<Object,Object> cacheConfiguration = CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(
                Object.class,
                Object.class,
                resourcePools).
                build();

        Map<String, CacheConfiguration<?, ?>> caches = new HashMap<>();
        caches.put("myCache", cacheConfiguration);

        EhcacheCachingProvider provider = (EhcacheCachingProvider) Caching.getCachingProvider("org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider");
        org.ehcache.config.Configuration configuration = new DefaultConfiguration(caches, provider.getDefaultClassLoader());

        return  provider.getCacheManager(provider.getDefaultURI(), (org.ehcache.config.Configuration) configuration);
    }

}
```

If you're using spring-boot, it should auto configure the JCacheCacheManager for you. You can then use a `JCacheManagerCustomizer` to configure the cache.