# Ehcache 3 spring boot not working in integration test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ehcache, ehcache-3

I need your help please. I integrated Ehcache 3 with springboot 2. everything works perfectly in production. integration tests also work if i execute them manualy ( I'm using Intellij IDE ).
but when i run "mvn install", i get this error :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'ehCacheManager' defined in class path
> resource [com/afklm/belem/payment/config/EhCacheConfiguration.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.springframework.cache.CacheManager]: Factory method
> 'ehCacheManager' threw exception; nested exception is
> javax.cache.CacheException: A Cache named [currenciesCache] already
> exists

**CurrencyRepository  interface** :

```
@Repository
public interface CurrencyRepository extends JpaRepository<Currency, String> {
    /**
     * Gets currencies from Cache.
     * The real call to the DataBase will be performed if the response is not in cache
     *
     * @return list of {@link Currency}
     */
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "currenciesCache", key ="#root.methodName", unless = "#result==null or #result.size()==0")
    default List<Currency> getCachedCurrencies() {
        return findAll();
    }
```

**Cache configuration class**

```
import org.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration;
import org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheConfigurationBuilder;
import org.ehcache.config.builders.ExpiryPolicyBuilder;
import org.ehcache.config.builders.ResourcePoolsBuilder;
import org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107Configuration;

import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachingConfigurerSupport;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheCacheManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;

import javax.cache.Caching;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.List;


@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class EhCacheConfiguration extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager ehCacheManager() {

        //-> currencies cache configuration
        CacheConfiguration<String, List> currenciesCacheConfig =
                CacheConfigurationBuilder
                        .newCacheConfigurationBuilder(String.class, List.class, ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(1000))
                        .withExpiry(ExpiryPolicyBuilder.timeToLiveExpiration(Duration.ofDays(30)))
                        .withDefaultEventListenersThreadPool()
                        .build();

        javax.cache.CacheManager cacheManager = Caching.getCachingProvider().getCacheManager();

        cacheManager.createCache("currenciesCache", Eh107Configuration.fromEhcacheCacheConfiguration(currenciesCacheConfig));

  

        return  new JCacheCacheManager(cacheManager);
    }
```

Thanks for your help; i'm stuck

Comment: pleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaase help

Answer (score 0):

I think I faced this before when at least one of my tests had the `@DirtiesContext` annotation which re-initializes the Spring context. I got around it by making a call to the `cacheManager.destroyCache` method before attempting to create the cache. Can you try adding the statement `cacheManager.destroyCache("currenciesCache");` before the `cacheManager.createCache` statement? Alternatively, you could try initializing the cache manager without the explicit call to the `createCache` method like it has been done in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53929804/converting-ehcache-cachemanager-v-3-x-to-spring-cachemanager-without-xml-confi)